# Case When Distinct value then sum another value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Piggy backing off another question I had yesterday.

I was wondering how I would go about counting the distinct number of records that have an amt > 1500.  The way my data is joined, I could have the same PKey AcctNo reflected more than one time because my full outer joined to another table that has multiple transactional records.

```
(Case When AcctNo_PKey = distinct then sum(case when amount > 1500 then 1 else 0 end)
 else 0) end as GT1500
```

this my current code that produces a desired result.  I

```
SELECT sum(case when amount > 1500 then 1 else 0 end) as GT1500
     , sum(case when amount < 1500 then 1 else 0 end) as LT1500
    , DATEPART(Year, amount.Date) Deposit_Year
    , DATEPART(QUARTER, amount.Date) Deposit_Qtr 
From account 
full outer JOIN amount ON account.AcctNo = amount.AcctNo
group by DATEPART(Year, amount.Date)
    , DATEPART(QUARTER, amount.Date)
```

Or maybe my entire approach is wrong...idk

Comment: Btw, i'm missing a `E1500` column ;)

Comment: What table does the column amount come from? You should use aliases to help identify where columns are. As coded you have a table and a column both named amount. I don't think this query would work as posted.

Comment: @TimSchmelter  not sure I follow

Comment: you are not handling = 1500, you are handling greater and less but not equal 1500.... could happend

Comment: @SeanLange I reposted the code from yesterday.  By accident I posted the code from my query at the office

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT )` on the output of a `CASE` expression. For example, to count the number of distinct `AcctNo_Pkey`s that have an `[amount] < 1500` row somewhere in the aggregated result, you could use this:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN [amount] < 1500 THEN AcctNo_PKey END)
```

Which you can see in action [in this minimal sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d00c3/1)

Comment: and there you go, that's all I needed to do.  Thanks a ton @dan and everyone else