# Python: Get DISTINCT column values from inside CASE function in pandasql

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, pandasql

I am trying to write a query in Python using `pandasql`. My code is as below,

```
import pandas as pd
from pandasql import *

data = pd.read_csv('registerlog.csv')

q = """
SELECT
    a.RegistrationMonth, COUNT(DISTINCT a.UserID) AS UserSize,
    COUNT(
        CASE a.MonthDifference
            WHEN 0.0 THEN DISTINCT a.UserID ELSE NULL
        END
    ) AS MonthZero
FROM
    data) AS a
GROUP BY
    a.RegistrationMonth
"""

print sqldf(q, locals())
```

But this gives the following error,

> print sqldf(q, locals())   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandasql\sqldf.py", line 156, in sqldf
>       return PandaSQL(db_uri)(query, env)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandasql\sqldf.py", line 63, in
>   **call**
>       raise PandaSQLException(ex) PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "DISTINCT": syntax error

But if I use `WHEN 0.0 THEN a.user_id ELSE NULL` then it works. Also the normal way of `COUNT(DISTINCT a.user_id)` also works fine.

But I want to get only the `DISTINCT` values inside the `CASE`. Is there a way to achieve this to get the `DISTINCT` count value inside the `CASE`?

Comment: Did you try `COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE ... END)) AS MonthZero`?

Comment: Did some searching and it appears that using DISTINCT inside a CASE statement is problematic... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687345/case-when-distinct-value-then-sum-another-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the SQL grammer, DISTINCT does not belong to any values (expressions), but to the SELECT or the aggregate function (here: COUNT). So you have to write it directly after the SELECT or the opening parenthesis:

```sql
SELECT ..., COUNT(DISTINCT CASE ... END) ...
```